# Is there a way to transfer a Github repository to a group?

Tags: github

I am currently doing development work on a repository that is owned by my department's group. In one of the repositories, I have admin privileges. What I want to do is make the code of this repository private and to upload a second repository that simply lists all of the issues from the original repository.

I have created a blank repository under my own account, and I intend to transfer ownership to the department's github account. My problem is that I cannot transfer the ownership of the new issues-only repository to an account that I do not have login-access to. Is there any way of getting around this?

Edit: I have already tried transferring ownership, but I get the error:
"You don’t have the permission to create public repositories on [groupname]"

Comment: Can't they just fork it before you private that repo?

Answer (score 1):

You could transfer a repository to another user (and don't need his credentials), it's under settings:

> Transfer ownership
>
> Transfer this repository to another user or to an organization where you have the ability to create repositories.

See also: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I should have specified earlier: when I try to do this, I get the following error: "You don’t have the permission to create public repositories on [groupname]."

Comment: Is [groupname] an organization here? Could you transfer it to another user? Then transfer to the admin of the organization, and then he could transfer it further